# I can not handle error?

Tags: android, error-handling

I have method

```
 public static List<Transaction> getTransactions(){
 if (ShoppingSessionDao.getCurrentShoppingSession()==null){
            //what return?
        }
        return new Select().from(Transaction.class).where("shoppingSession = ?",
                    ShoppingSessionDao.getCurrentShoppingSession().getId()).execute();
    }
```

It return me List with data.

Then I do

```
private void setData() {
    transactionList = TransactionDao.getTransactions();
    baseAdapter = new BasketAdapter(transactionList);
    gridView.setAdapter(baseAdapter);
}
```

but sometimes (if `ShoppingSession` is empty) `ShoppingSessionDao.getCurrentShoppingSession()`return me NULL.

How can I handle this error?

**solution**

```
private void setData() {
        ShoppingSession shoppingSession = ShoppingSessionDao.getCurrentShoppingSession();
        if (shoppingSession==null){
            return;
        }
        transactionList = TransactionDao.getTransactions(shoppingSession);
        baseAdapter = new BasketAdapter(transactionList);
        gridView.setAdapter(baseAdapter);
        tvPrice.setText(calculateTotalSum());
    }
```

and

```
public static List<Transaction> getTransactions(ShoppingSession shoppingSession){
        return new Select().from(Transaction.class).where("shoppingSession = ?",
                shoppingSession.getId()).execute();
    }
```

Comment: add a try catch exception

Comment: @"what return?" return null and handle it in the caller method? Is that even a 'good' SO question? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it there are two ways for you to implement this. Solution one is to surround your code with a try catch like this:

```
try {       
        ShoppingSession shoppingSession = ShoppingSessionDao.getCurrentShoppingSession();
        transactionList = TransactionDao.getTransactions(shoppingSession);
        baseAdapter = new BasketAdapter(transactionList);
        gridView.setAdapter(baseAdapter);
        tvPrice.setText(calculateTotalSum());

    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        Log.e("Error: ", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
//Do error handling here
    }
```

Another way to do this is an extension of the current method you are using by using the following code:

```
ShoppingSession shoppingSession = ShoppingSessionDao.getCurrentShoppingSession();
        if (shoppingSession != null) {
            transactionList = TransactionDao.getTransactions(shoppingSession);
            baseAdapter = new BasketAdapter(transactionList);
            gridView.setAdapter(baseAdapter);
            tvPrice.setText(calculateTotalSum());
        } else {
            tvPrice.setText("Shopping session is null");
//Do error handling here
        }
```